# Meaning of トルネル is actually misspelling of トンネル?

Tags: translation, katakana

I need to know what トルネル means in the following sentence from a manga I'm reading (slashes are where the line-breaks are):

この**トルネル**から　／　出る！

The katakana is throwing me off. Is it one or two words? Is it a Japanese word that's written in katakana for emphasis? Is it a foreign word? Is it misspelled?

For context purposes, I've added the previous sentence in parentheses here:

（この人が言うことは　／　無茶ばかりだけど）
この**トルネル**から　／　出る！

Below, I've added a photo of the page where the text comes from. It's to the left of the binding superimposed on top of the girl blushing.

[image]

Comment: Can you double check that it's not トンネル?

Comment: @snailboat: I added a photo of where the sentence came from for clarification. I did find トンネル when I was looking for the meaning of the word, but that didn't make sense.

Comment: I still think this is a typo for トンネル. It should be a metaphor for "dark days" or something like that. (Googling 塚本敦史 gave no relevant results. Is this a proofread manga from a large publisher?)

Comment: @naruto: Yes, this manga was published by Ohzora Shippun. I'm not reading from the magazine, but from the tankobon so I'm assuming that any discrepancies in the magazine would've been resolved by the time the tankobon was released... but I could be wrong. The "dark days" angle might work for me, but I'm still holding to see if there is a more concrete answer.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB%22%20%E3%83%88%E3%83%B3%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB) seems to indicate that it's a somewhat common typo for トンネル, where you can see people otherwise typing トンネル on the same page. Weird that it would make it to print though, even for a third-tier publisher.

Comment: @naruto: thanks for the info. I believe you are correct, especially since you are a native speaker. If this question ever get off of the "on hold" status, I'll check mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @mirka: thanks for validating naruto's assessment. Reading further into the manga, using トンネル makes sense.

Comment: @Rose By the way, you can't mark a comment as an answer.

Comment: @akj: I know that, but my question was put on hold and I wanted to let naruto and mirka know that I acknowledged their comments and this was the only way.